# How to launch containing app from custom keyboard extension?

Tags: ios, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard

I saw some posts about that question, but still don't get it.

I set URLidentifier for containing app - KbrdApp. If my containing app launches it returns flag '1' that means 'ready'.

This is the code from custom keyboard extension called from `viewDidLoad`:

```
UIWebView * webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
NSString *customURL = @"KbrdApp://";
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:customURL]];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

I have read that `NSExtensionContext` works only with Today extension, so I tried `UIWebView`. But it doesn't work.

What is wrong?

Comment: if you got the answer then please post your code...I am having same problem...Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The approach mentioned in the question stoped working in iOS 8.0.

Currently (iOS 9.2) you can use several ways to access shared `UIApplication` instance and its hidden `openURL` method.

Personally, I prefer this approach witch I have developed:

```
// Usage:
// UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "your-app-scheme://")!)

extension UIApplication {

    public static func sharedApplication() -> UIApplication {
        guard UIApplication.respondsToSelector("sharedApplication") else {
            fatalError("UIApplication.sharedKeyboardApplication(): `UIApplication` does not respond to selector `sharedApplication`.")
        }

        guard let unmanagedSharedApplication = UIApplication.performSelector("sharedApplication") else {
            fatalError("UIApplication.sharedKeyboardApplication(): `UIApplication.sharedApplication()` returned `nil`.")
        }

        guard let sharedApplication = unmanagedSharedApplication.takeUnretainedValue() as? UIApplication else {
            fatalError("UIApplication.sharedKeyboardApplication(): `UIApplication.sharedApplication()` returned not `UIApplication` instance.")
        }

        return sharedApplication
    }

    public func openURL(url: NSURL) -> Bool {
        return self.performSelector("openURL:", withObject: url) != nil
    }

}
```

Comment:   symbol matters. My code does not call `sharedApplication` at all. The code just introduced function `UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)` that just works.

Answer (score 1):

This is my version of the obj c language. Works on IOS 11.4.1, XCode 9.4.1

Category for UIApplication class:

```
// UIApplication+UpenURL.h file
@interface UIApplication (OpenUrlHelper)

+ (UIApplication *)sharedApp;
- (void)openUrl:(NSURL *)url withOptions:(NSDictionary *)options andComplition:(void(^)(BOOL))complition;

@end

// UIApplication+UpenURL.m file
#import "UIApplication+UpenURL.h"
@implementation UIApplication (OpenUrlHelper)

+ (UIApplication *)sharedApp {
    __weak UIApplication *sharedApp = [UIApplication performSelector:@selector(sharedApplication)];
    return sharedApp;
}

- (void)openUrl:(NSURL *)url withOptions:(NSDictionary *)options andComplition:(void(^)(BOOL))complition {
    if (@available (iOS 10, *)) {
        [self performSelector:@selector(openURL:options:completionHandler:)
                   withObject:url
                   withObject:options
                   withObject:complition];
    } else {
        [self performSelector:@selector(openURL:) withObject:url];
    }
}

- (id)performSelector:(SEL)selector withObject:(id)obj1 withObject:(id)obj2 withObject:(id)obj3 {
    NSMethodSignature *signature = [self methodSignatureForSelector:selector];
    if (!signature)
        return nil;

    NSInvocation* invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:signature];
    [invocation setTarget:self];
    [invocation setSelector:selector];
    [invocation setArgument:&obj1 atIndex:2];
    [invocation setArgument:&obj2 atIndex:3];
    [invocation setArgument:&obj3 atIndex:4];
    [invocation invoke];
    if (signature.methodReturnLength) {
        id anObject;
        [invocation getReturnValue:&anObject];
        return anObject;
    }
    return nil;
}

@end
```

then in file where you need it you should

```
#import "UIApplication+UpenURL.h"
```

and use code like this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"yourapp://"];
[[UIApplication sharedApp] openUrl:url withOptions:@{} andComplition:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, this helped me a lot after wasting my 3 hours time behind other solutions